# Why is my tasks.loop not working on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a cog named `wednesday` that prints a certain image from an `images` folder, as the name suggests, every Wednesday. For testing purposes, however, I've made the loop run every 30 seconds, and I've made it so that it runs today (Monday) instead of Wednesday. I've tried running this code locally on my computer, and it works with no issues. However, after deploying to Heroku, the loop doesn't work at all. Keep in mind that I have another cog that has a `tasks.loop` as well, which changes the status of my bot every few seconds. That cog, however, works without any issues on Heroku. As I said before, this `wednesday` cog works locally on my machine, which means that I'm properly adding and loading the cog for my bot, and doing other things that are required for the code to run. So, why is my code not working on Heroku?

```py
import discord, datetime
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import json

with open('config.json') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

class wednesday(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @tasks.loop(seconds=30)
    async def time_checker(self):
        self.time = datetime.datetime.now
        if self.time().hour == 19:
            if datetime.datetime.today().weekday() == 0: # 0 because I'm testing today which is a Monday
                self.channel = await self.bot.fetch_channel(config['id'])
                await self.channel.send(file=discord.File('images/wednesday_pic.png'))
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        self.time_checker.start()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(wednesday(bot))
```

I'm not sure why this is happening: I think it might have something to do with the loop. I have other images in the `images` folder that work fine for other commands that I have, as the bot sends them when I call the command. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem instead of just saying "this is not working". Provide a full traceback or an error report, otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: Well that's the thing: there are no errors.

Comment: Does opening the image work? In heroku

Comment: The images along with all the other files are deployed from my GitHub repo, since I've changed the setting on Heroku, which re-deploys every time I push to my repository. So, if I check my git repo, I can see my images.

Comment: Try opening the file or print debugging, you need to figure out where the code goes wrong, wether your command is not being executed or if your error handler eats it up the error or the image is not loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what was causing the error. The Heroku servers run on the UTC time zone, and I am on the PST/PDT time zone. So, I used a UTC to PDT [converter](https://savvytime.com/converter/utc-to-pst) to get the appropriate time that I was looking for the loop to print out the image. Here is the final code:

```py
import discord, datetime
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import json

with open('config.json') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

class wednesday(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @tasks.loop(hours=1)
    async def time_checker(self):
        self.channel = await self.bot.fetch_channel(config['channel'])
        self.time = datetime.datetime.now
        if self.time().hour == 12:
            if datetime.datetime.today().weekday() == 3:
                await self.channel.send(file=discord.File('images/wednesday_pic.png'))
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        self.time_checker.start()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(wednesday(bot))
```

Answer (score 1):

We need more debugging details. You may find out what the mistake is when doing the debugging.

1. Check `requirements.txt` and ensure the versions are locked. (Likely the case if you generated it through `pip freeze`. If not: Make sure the versions on your local development environment is the same as on Heroku.
2. Add more logs. Logs when your `cog` is loaded. Logs when your task is repeatedly executed along with the values of your variables. Logs that print out your current working directory (`import os; print(os.getcwd())`)
3. Check how far your bot reaches. Is it failing at the very beginning and it does not come online? Is the cog not being loaded? Is it the task routine? Is it the path resolution?
4. Provide the logs. Don't cut off the logs. Provide the entire thing. They may not seem relevant to your but other readers may spot something.
5. You provided there a relative path for your image. Provide information of your project folder structure. What's the command used to execute your project (`Procfile`, can also be seen in the logs.)